# Can't get theme-specific modules to work in Prestashop 1.7.x

Tags: prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I'm developing a custom module for Prestashop 1.7.x and it has to be a theme-specific module.

I've followed the guidelines from the official documentation, I've put my module in `my-theme/modules/` and declared it as a theme dependency in the `theme.yml` configuration file, but nothing seems to happen.

The module display in the modules catalog only if it's located in the Prestashop root `/modules` folder.

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation (and the internet) is void when trying to understand the concept of theme-specific modules.

The theme's `modules` folder is dedicated to [overriding the templates and assets of any module](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/themes/reference/overriding-modules/).

You want to add your theme-specific module in the `dependencies/modules` folder, then declare it in your theme's configuration (`config/theme.yml`):

```yaml
dependencies:
  modules:
    - yourmodule

global_settings:
  modules:
    to_enable:
      - yourmodule
```

When installing your theme from a ZIP file, [Prestashop will move the modules contained in this folder](https://github.com/Prestashop/Prestashop/blob/1.7.7.x/src/Core/Addon/Theme/ThemeManager.php#L431-L446).

They won't be installed and enabled, [this is done when enabling the theme](https://github.com/Prestashop/Prestashop/blob/1.7.7.x/src/Core/Addon/Theme/ThemeManager.php#L338-L355) (given that you specified to enable it in your theme's configuration as seen above).

Comment: Is there something else to do? I did exactly this with `dependencies/modules/my_custom_module` but when I enable the theme it says "Cannot install module my_custom_module. The module my_custom_module could not be found on Addons.".

Comment: I had to copy it by myself into `modules/` (in fact I did a symlink) for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

theme/modules are for overrides, it will override only the modules that are already installed.

theme/dependencies are for dependencies, the modules you put there will be installed when you install the theme (you have to install with a zip file from the prestashop admin UI, dont try to just copy/past the theme on your FTP).

When you install your theme, prestashop will copy the files from the dependencies directory to root/modules, then run the "install" method of each module.